# DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133) when opening Chrome on Windows 10 - WinDbg shows Kernel symbols are WRONG

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a HP laptop with Nvidia GEFORCE GTX 1060, I've been running Windows 10 version 1909 (OS Build 18363.959). Early this year, I upgraded Nvidia driver and started to encounter BSOD every time I opened Chrome (latest version, with hardware acceleration turned on).

The stop code is: `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION`

I doubted it was caused by Nvidia driver upgrade, and I tried the following to fix it:

1. Uninstall and install latest driver again from [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).
2. Turn off hardware acceleration in Chrome.

But still the same.

Then I installed WinDbg from Microsoft Store and opened [one of the mini dump files](https://mega.nz/file/o4hTGDwJ#Tc-VMM9QeoPKtoWI5sIN-5ztv0zKDoYjqXLJirLYbYk), executed `!analyze -v`, result showed `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION (133)` and `Kernel symbols are WRONG. Please fix symbols to do analysis.`

I tried commands `.symfix` and `.reload`, but WinDbg told me:

```
************* Symbol Loading Error Summary **************
Module name            Error
ntkrnlmp               The system cannot find the file specified
```

I then tried `sfc /scannow` but `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations`.

You can find the full log exported from WinDbg [here](https://mega.nz/file/RswBxDSR#aHec9vRWk9TgEbjMD725_l4D_bUQ9TNHK7RE8GPVzo4).

How can I fix this wrong symbol error so that WinDbg can continue further analyzsis on the real root cause of the `DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION` error?